# How can I make a side navbar that resizes to the devices screen (and make a top navbar next to it)?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I know how to create a navbar that changes to the screens size on the top of an HTML page with CSS, but not putting it on the side. I checked w3schools and Google, no prevail. Is there an easy way to do it to make it kinda look like discord but only with the left navbar (for servers) and the top (server info)?

Answer (score 0):

You can style it with `width: 100%;` or `height: 100%;` depending on its rotation. This will make it take up the entire screen's height/ width. Make sure you have it hitting the edges by making the page's margin set to 0.